# How do I prevent a view's height from being set by its XIB?

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, interface-builder, xib

If I create a view in a XIB, instantiate it programmatically in a view controller, and the display it, the view remains the same size as it was in the XIB. If I try to provide Auto Layout constraints to correct this, it generally ends up conflicting with a `UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height` constraint that's set by the layout system.

How can I get rid of this height constraint that's coming from the XIB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is set the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` property on the view to `NO`. This tells the layout system not to automatically create any constraints from values you've set in your XIB like the freeform height of your view. Only constraints you've explicitly laid out in Interface Builder will be created at runtime.

For example:

```
NSArray<UIView *> *views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass([MyCustomView class]) owner:self options:nil];

MyCustomView *view = (MyCustomView *)views.firstObject;
view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```